# The most precision way to get connection time JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public class Sql {
    private static Connection con=null;
    private static Statement stat=null;

    public void createConnection(){
        try {
            long a = System.currentTimeMillis();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","root","");
            stat = con.createStatement();
            //result in milliseconds
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - a); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

it is piece of code which provide us connection to localhost source. i create there method which giving result of time taken to connect using System.currentTimeMillis(). is there any other way to get more precision value?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the monitoring tool. This will greatly help as you develop you application further by not ending up System prints in all your JDBC calls.

http://www.jdbmonitor.com/

Answer (score 1):

you could use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) *but I remember reading somewhere that it wasn't guaranteed your results would be consistent*

Edit: from the docs I linked:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().